# Find and remove a group tag in VScode

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I have several XML files which all have the same tag name at the beginning : <layer name="xxxx" ...

I would like to be able to select in VSCode the tag that corresponds to this word in each file with the search and replace function in 1 time, and delete the whole group easily.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oISFB.png]

Here is the group that always starts with <layer name="Watermarks", the id is different for each file.

Comment: are there possible `layer` tags inside

Comment: Yes there are several Layer tags in the file

Comment: I ask if there are `layer` tags inside a `layer` tag

Answer (score 0):

If there are no other `layer` tags inside

```
<layer name="Watermarks"[\s\S]*?</layer>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but it doesn't work with the Search function.

Answer (score 0):

```
<layer name="Watermark[\s\S\r]*?</layer>
```

I just found the solution by adding \r
I also had to remove the "behind Watermarks" because it was not in the whole file.